# Android feedback via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to create an Android app which provides a user with feedback such as haptic/textual based on a bluetooth signal it receives from a transmitter.

Could anyone recommend any article/book where I could get some good information? Can't seem to find anything useful myself.

Much thanks.

Shaw